# R UCM time series - force variables to be positive

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I am using R, the package *rucm*, in order to build an unobserved component model for a time series. Now using this approach is mandatory, so I can't change the model.

The problem arises after my model is build. So I took the usual steps to build my model (unfortunately I can't share the data but I did provide a mock one), like this :

```
library(rucm)
    data_set <- read.table(header=T, text='Date y x1 x2 x3
1/1/2015 0:00 2.079441542 1.791759469 1.098612289 1.098612289
1/2/2015 0:00 1.386294361 1.609437912 1.609437912 0
1/3/2015 0:00 2.302585093 1.945910149 1.791759469 0
1/4/2015 0:00 1.098612289 1.945910149 2.197224577 0.693147181
1/5/2015 0:00 0.693147181 1.609437912 2.079441542 0.693147181
1/6/2015 0:00 1.098612289 0.693147181 1.945910149 0.693147181
1/7/2015 0:00 2.302585093 0 2.302585093 1.098612289
1/8/2015 0:00 0.693147181 1.609437912 1.791759469 0.693147181
1/9/2015 0:00 1.945910149 1.386294361 1.098612289 0
1/10/2015 0:00 1.791759469 2.079441542 2.197224577 0.693147181
1/11/2015 0:00 0.693147181 0 1.386294361 0
1/12/2015 0:00 1.098612289 2.079441542 1.386294361 0.693147181
1/13/2015 0:00 1.945910149 1.386294361 0 0
1/14/2015 0:00 1.609437912 0 2.197224577 0.693147181
1/15/2015 0:00 0 1.609437912 2.079441542 0
1/16/2015 0:00 1.609437912 2.302585093 2.197224577 0
1/17/2015 0:00 2.302585093 0.693147181 1.945910149 0
1/18/2015 0:00 2.079441542 1.791759469 1.609437912 0
1/19/2015 0:00 1.791759469 1.098612289 1.386294361 0.693147181
1/20/2015 0:00 0.693147181 2.079441542 1.386294361 0
1/21/2015 0:00 1.609437912 2.197224577 0.693147181 0.693147181
1/22/2015 0:00 2.302585093 2.302585093 1.609437912 0
1/23/2015 0:00 1.609437912 2.197224577 2.197224577 0
1/24/2015 0:00 1.945910149 0.693147181 1.791759469 0
1/25/2015 0:00 0 1.945910149 1.609437912 0.693147181
1/26/2015 0:00 0.693147181 1.609437912 1.098612289 1.098612289
1/27/2015 0:00 0.693147181 1.609437912 2.197224577 0.693147181
1/28/2015 0:00 1.098612289 1.098612289 2.079441542 0
1/29/2015 0:00 2.302585093 2.302585093 1.386294361 0.693147181')



model_ucm = ucm(y ~ x1+x2+x3,data=data_set , slope=T)
model_ucm
```

In the output, some coefficients are negative. But I know, or at least, I expect those certain coefficients to be positive. They have to. Because the variables that yield this effect are expected to be positive, from a business perspective.

Is there a way to force some variables to be positive, in this model? 
As you can see from the output, *x3* has a negative coefficient and I want it to be positive, the rest can remain negative.

```
   Estimate Approx.StdErr   t.val p.value
x1 -0.05320       0.20271 -0.2624  0.7950
x2 -0.19880       0.26437 -0.7520  0.4588
x3 -0.23300       0.33990 -0.6855  0.4991
```

Comment: Can you provide at least artificial `data_set` so it will make it easier to help you?

Comment: Often the statistical properties of models and estimators chance when you have bounding conditions. You should probably consult the statisticians over  at [stats.se] to see what the appropriate model for your data might be depending on what types of inference you want to make. This really isn't a programming question so much as it is a statistical modeling question.

Comment: I added a sample data set also